# Remove image in post when it's removed in media library

Tags: plugin-development, media-library

As the title says, I want to automatically remove a specific image in all posts where it's used when I remove the image from the media library. Because at the moment, if I remove an image from the media library the "empty image" stays in the post(so all the html code) but nothing is being displayed of course.
Is there any way/plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find plugin for that and I think there might be a problem to find one.

Problem is not easy to solve because as I just checked in WordPress database reference (http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png) there is not special container for images in post content.

If I understand correct your plugin needs to:

- hook to action when media is removed,
- search through all your posts looking for image url,
- find in post content image url and html 'a' tag for it,
- remove 'a' tag with image tag

It is not soo hard to write it but performence of plugin depends on how many posts you have on your blog.

Comment: That's what I thought, I'll have to do it the hard way with regex :) I'll have to code it tomorrow then and post my results here. If anybody got any other suggestions that would be great.